# VBA inserted building block not printing

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to programmatically insert a building block into Microsoft Word using VBA, and while the insertion works, when viewing in print preview, and when printing, the building block does not appear.

```
Sub draw_point()
Dim objTemplate As Template
Dim objBB As BuildingBlock

    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1

    ' Set the template to store the building block
    Set objTemplate = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate

    ' Access the building block through the type and category
    Set objBB = objTemplate.BuildingBlockTypes(wdTypeAutoText) _
    .Categories("General").BuildingBlocks("point")

    ' Insert the building block into the document replacing any selected text.
    objBB.Insert Selection.Range
End Sub
```

If I manually insert the building block it prints fine.

I am creating the building block by inserting a shape, then adding it to

```
AutoText > General > Normal.dotm > Insert content only
```

If I try to re-create this issue on a new document, it does not happen, but I'm unsure what properties differs between the two documents

Comment: When you manually insert it are you inserting in the exact same place? When you insert it from your code is it being inserted into a paragraph where the font is hidden?

Comment: The shape was being inserted into a table cell that had hidden font. After fixing this it now prints. If you want to write up an answer, I'll except it.

Comment: Thank you, answer duly written up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shape disappears in print preview it is probably because in the Font settings for the paragraph where the shape is anchored the Hidden property is set.

This would also explain why you can't replicate the issue in a different document.